# Add RajawaliRenderer as a View

Tags: android, rajawali

I'm really new to Rajawali and was hoping to use a lot of their 3D functionality with the Android camera.  My goal is to display a 3D object on a camera SurfaceView.

When doing this with a 2D object using native Android, the steps were:

1. Get camera and a holder
2. Create `SurfaceView` for the holder
3. Display the camera preview
4. Use a subclass of `GLSurfaceView` to draw stuff during the `onDraw()` call

My steps to do this using Rajawali are similar, except step 4. is now a subclass of `RajawaliRenderer`.

The problem is that the subclass of `GLSurfaceView` could be added as a child to the preview `SurfaceView`.  `RajawaliRendered` has a method to `getCurrentView()`, but this returns null though the object has been constructed.

Any ideas?

Comment: can you share your code, you have done up to now.

Comment: Sure, I actually got it all working.  I'll post an answer later in the day to show the solution.

Comment: If you would post that code it'd be really helpful! Perhaps as an answer?

Comment: @Austin please share your answer :)